# why kotlin by lazy can cause memory leak in android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kotlin

I define a loading Dialog like this

```
private val loadingDialog: LoadingDialog by lazy { LoadingDialog() }
```

`loadingDialog` is a `DialogFragment`

when I use `leakcanary` to watch my app, I find the `loadingDialog` cause memory

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you please share the whole message given by canary?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you define a `val` delegated `by lazy {...}`, the lambda you pass to the delegate captures the scope into its closure (though it's only the outer `this` in your case, it may be an `Activity` instance).

Then the delegate instance holds the references it captured until the moment the `val` is first accessed. Then it invokes the lambda and 'forgets' the closure.

But if your `val` is accessed too late (or never), the lambda's closure may keep the objects in memory that would otherwise be disposed, which is a possible memory leak.

Comment: Yes! To make it work, you have to be careful about which object holds the delegated property and limit that to objects whose lifecycle is in sync with the resources used in the lambda. By 'in sync' I mean that those objects should not live longer than any of the referenced resources, such as `Activity` in the question.

Comment: Understood, is there any way to get rid of these lately initialized `val` properties once it has been accessed? @hotkey